# Hamburger doesn't work

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I managed to create a drawer and have the hamburger sign but the hamburger is not working when tapped. Also how can I change the code so that my app has a transparent notification bar so that the color is same(or preferably a little darker) and one can see the app drawer opened in status bar. Something like this: [Transparent status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09yA.png)

**FirstActivity.java:**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_me_clicked);
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);    //removes the package name from toolbar

//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance          //Integration of app into status bar
//            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
//        }

    // These lines are needed to display the top-left hamburger button
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // Make the hamburger button work
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DL);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }
    };
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // toasts the message when ListView item is clicked
    ListView mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String drawerstring = ("Menu Item at position " + position + " clicked.");
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),drawerstring,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: put your activity_me_clicked.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You have to override onOptionsItemSelected and handle the home item to open the drawer.  Its not done for you, because Android doesn't know what you're using that button for (home?  back?  hamburger?  Something else?).  The ActionDrawerToggle knows how to handle it if you want to just delegate it.

Comment: Also how can I achieve the Transparent status Bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i09yA.png.